Random Data Loss with Html Webform Submission with php on Website
I have a simple website built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It’s hosted on a local cloud provider, with PHP handling backend operations. The website is straightforward, and I’ve implemented a Cloudflare CAPTCHA challenge to enhance security.
The website allows users to submit data via a form. After clicking the submit button, the PHP script processes the input and uses cURL to send the data to an endpoint. However, I’ve been facing an issue for over a month where the database shows a new row being created, but all the input fields are empty.
Setup Details:
Frontend: HTML/CSS/JavaScript.
Backend: PHP with cURL for GET and POST requests.
Infrastructure:
A proxy server is configured between the website and the database endpoint to handle requests and resolve CORS issues.
Nginx is installed and configured.
Logs:
Apache logs show the submitted data.
The endpoint’s HTTP log also shows that a request is received.
However, the database at the endpoint only has empty rows.
Additional Notes:
The issue occurs randomly.
No errors or warnings are displayed after the form submission.
Temporarily disabling the Cloudflare CAPTCHA didn’t resolve the problem.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified that form inputs are being sent from the frontend to the PHP script.
Logged the raw data received by PHP using var_dump($_POST) and file_get_contents('php://input').
Checked the cURL payload sent by PHP to ensure the data is properly structured.
Reviewed the proxy server configuration to confirm that all headers and request bodies are being forwarded correctly.
Examined the endpoint’s API response for any errors or rejections.
Analyzed Apache, Nginx, and endpoint logs to trace the issue.
Despite these efforts, I cannot identify why the input fields are missing in the database rows.

You already did quite a bit of debugging, but the results of that are only vaguely described. We also can't see any of the code. What do you expect of us? Make a random guess? My best guess is that a web-robot/spider discovered your form submission script, and simply calls it without any data. Of course I can't tell why your CAPTCHA challenge wouldn't stop such a submission.

Does your PHP code check the payload to ensure that the input fields are not blank? If it does and the blank rows still appear, the problem is in the back end. If it doesn't, there's probably no data loss and you can proceed accordingly. In any event, it's always a good idea to post (relevant!) code with the question, so we don't have no guess.
